# How to clean MySQL database containing NULL Characters?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

MySQL database contains a lots of columns containing NULL values. I want to clean my database from Null characters without losing my data.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean for "clean my database from Null characters" .. thiss not clear .. .. please explain better

Comment: explain it little more, if you can explain with an example it will be good to in knowing the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: Do you want to replace NULL values with some other values? You can't just arbitrarily add data to the db. NULL values indicate lack of relevant data. Clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: A) Why do you want to remove NULL values? B) What is an example of these values? C) Do you have **backups of your data**?

Comment: A [null character](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) is not the same as [Null (SQL)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)) which are you asking about?

Comment: Here is screen capture http://screencast.com/t/lFYqoeRzgMX that shows error while importing db through mysql workbench.

while importing through SQLyog is do not gives any error. 

so is it really an  issue of Null values?